# Source of overhead in model.fit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a code where I make repeated calls to model.fit()

(It's for implementing an A2C)

I've noticed that my first call to model.fit() has significant overhead, but not the calls afterwards.

So my question is what are the common causes of overhead for model.fit() and some potential fixes?

I'm using Tensorflow2.0 and python3.

Comment: how can we help without seeing your code ?

Comment: The major cause of overhead in the first call is graph creation - TF2.x has to create the computation graph internally, at runtime. This involves assigning tensors in memory, which has an even greater overhead if the GPU is involved.

Comment: One way to circumvent this is to call the model on dummy data at the beginning of the script, before the actual calls.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Wouldn't initializing the model before calling a model.fit() solve this issue? Also is there a way to call a fit on the dummy data without actually changing the model's weights?

Comment: No, tensorflow defers the graph creation till the first call to model, not its initialization. Also, unless you manually change the weights (using your custom code or through TF's optimizer methods), the model's weights will remain fixed for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it tomorrow and if it works I will mark your comment as an answer

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal It did work, I'll mark your comment as an answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by [Susmit Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5533928/susmit-agrawal) worked for me.

"The major cause of overhead in the first call is graph creation - TF2.x has to create the computation graph internally, at runtime. This involves assigning tensors in memory, which has an even greater overhead if the GPU is involved."

The solution was to run a model.fit() with numpy.zeros() as the dummy data prior to the actual execution of the loop with all my calls to model.fit().